# iOS Build Automation ipa Packaging Fails with Cannot Read Format Tag

Tags: ios, automated-deploy, xcrun

So, previously I was having a problem signing the code, but I figured that out. On my next build attempt, I received:

```
Cannot read format tag from '/tmp/hl1WidCTwb/entitlements_rawxKfUuL3b':
```

I am unsure what to do next, and I can't really find any resources online.

I removed parts of the output for anonymity, but here is most of it:

```
lt-00003914:emulator Mobile$ sudo xcrun -sdk iphoneos7.0 PackageApplication -v Test.app -o /Users/Mobile/Desktop/somefile.ipa --sign "This is where my identity would go" --embed /Users/Mobile/Desktop/Provisioning\ Profiles/Demo_Version.mobileprovision 


### Checking original app

+ /usr/bin/codesign --verify -vvvv Test.app

Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 0 : [Test.app: valid on disk

Test.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement

]

Done checking the original app

### Embedding '/Users/Mobile/Desktop/Provisioning Profiles/Demo_Version.mobileprovision'

+ /bin/rm -rf /tmp/hl1WidCTwb/Payload/Test.app/embedded.mobileprovision

Program /bin/rm returned 0 : []

+ /bin/cp -rp /Users/Mobile/Desktop/Provisioning Profiles/Demo_Version.mobileprovision /tmp/hl1WidCTwb/Payload/Test.app/embedded.mobileprovision

Program /bin/cp returned 0 : []

+ /usr/bin/codesign -d --entitlements /tmp/hl1WidCTwb/entitlements_rawxKfUuL3b /tmp/hl1WidCTwb/Payload/Test.app

Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 0 : [Executable=/private/tmp/hl1WidCTwb/Payload/Test.app/Test

]

error: Cannot read format tag from '/tmp/hl1WidCTwb/entitlements_rawxKfUuL3b':
```

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to embed a provisioning profile with a different App ID?

Comment: I have no idea, but it mentions entitlements. Are you using an Entitlements.plist file, if so I've seen questions on here in the past where it has somehow become corrupted. Are you using a Bot or Jenkins or something else?

Comment: I am also seeing this - have you solved your issues?